# Get version number in maven without its type word

Tags: java, maven, shared-libraries, launch4j

How can I extract the `0.0.1` from the version property `${project.version}` of my `maven` project into a property?

---

`${project.version}` gets its value from the artifact version attribute:

```
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

I use the [launch4j maven plugin](https://github.com/lukaszlenart/launch4j-maven-plugin) which dictates me to set its version numbers in the schema of `x.x.x.x`. I want to use the extracted version as the required file version in the launch4j configuration as mentioned [here](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html#File) appending a final element `.0`:

```
<fileVersion>x.x.x.x</fileVersion>
```

Comment: This question needs a better description. Where are you trying to use this "property"? Somewhere else in the POM? To modify the XML file that launch4j uses? Something else?

Comment: Or is the real problem that the Maven property ends in `-SNAPSHOT` and launch4j doesn't like that?

Comment: Better question. Unfortunately, last I looked, Maven didn't support property transformation, but they may have changed that. There is an ugly hack here: https://gist.github.com/tux2323/970877

Comment: Check the [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/parse-version-mojo.html) to solve the problem.